# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, error-handling, casting

Here is my table structure
I am attaching the Image of table with records
[image: On this table structure]

When I am trying to getting the data from this table and want to display it on a page then i am getting error like this

**invalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'.
ThrowDataException
InvalidOperationException: Error parsing column 5 (EventTime=11:30:00 - Object)**

I am using this command  `select * from events` in stored procedure to get the all records from this table.
Data type of `EventTime`   column is time and when I am creating the property of this column on c# then the datatype is datetime
hiow can i resolve this problem?

here is the stored procedure code to understand better

```
USE [RG_DEC12]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetAllBlogs]    Script Date: 12/20/2016 12:01:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Gaurav Sharma>
-- Create date: <20/12/2016>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEvents]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   select * from Events

END
```

Comment: Please post the SP code

Comment: IMHO, you have the error when you try to display your result on client (post C# code). The SP it's OK

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer we need to cast eventtime column like this

`CONVERT(char(10), eventtime, 108) as EventTime`